# How do OpenMP thread ids work with recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, openmp

Here is a simple recursive program that splits into two for every recursive call. As expected, the result is 2 + 4 + 8 calls to rec, but the number of threads is always the same: two, and the ids bounce back and forth between 0 and one. I expected each recursive call to retain the id, and that 8 threads would be made in the end. What exactly is going on? Is there any issue with the code?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void rec(int n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return;

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
  {
    printf("Currently at %d -- total %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    rec(n - 1);
  }
}

int main() {
  omp_set_nested(1);
  rec(3);
}
```

Comment: Did you specify how many threads are available, for instance with the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I didn't explicitly set it, but the default in my environment is eight threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is working as expected by OpenMP standard. In [OpenMP documentation](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu111.html) you can find the following about `omp_get_num_threads`:

> Summary: The omp_get_num_threads routine returns the number of threads
> **in the current team**.
>
> Binding: The binding region for an omp_get_num_threads region is the
> **innermost enclosing parallel region**.
>
> Effect: The omp_get_num_threads routine returns the number of threads
> in the team that is executing the parallel region to which the routine
> region binds. If called from the sequential part of a program, this
> routine returns 1.

[omp_get_thread_num](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu113.html) has the same binding region:

> The binding region for an *omp_get_thread_num* region is the **innermost
> enclosing parallel region**.

It means that `omp_get_num_threads` and `omp_get_thread_num` bind to the innermost parallel region only, so it does not matter how many nested parallel regions are used. Each of your parallel regions is defined by `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)`, therefore the return value of `omp_get_num_threads` is 2 (as long as you have enough threads available) and the return value of `omp_get_thread_num` is either `0` or `1`.